# Is it required to add columns of ones to training data for Multivariate Linear Regression in scikit?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I've been going through various MOOCs online and one of them mentioned to include column of ones to the training data for Linear Regression in scikit.

Suppose i have the following training dataset:

```
investment    loan
    300000   12000
    431000    3000
    900000    4000
    320000    2000
```

Do i need to append column of ones like as following before fitting to scikit model for LinearRegression in python?

```
ones    investment    loan
   1        300000   12000
   1        431000    3000
   1        900000    4000
   1        320000    2000
```

Any help is thankful.

Comment: You should try to understand what this is doing (especially when you are working on courses). It's there to handle bias / centering. Now go to sklearn's docs and look if this bias-support is a parameter.

Comment: @sascha i have already gone through all related documents and in my opinion i am unable to find nothing on this topic in any docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html):

> fit_intercept : boolean, optional, default True
>
> whether to calculate the intercept for this model. If set to False, no
>   intercept will be used in calculations (e.g. data is expected to be
>   already centered).

The *intercept* is the coefficient related to a "column of 1s". So if this parameter is set to `True` (which is the default), you don't need your column of 1s.

Comment: Ah yes! actually. nice catch. Thank you @eqperes